# Error in action classes while using "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2"

Tags: java, selenium

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/73b57e0a-42de-4b91-9864-6edd30d7d2c1/moveto did not match a known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
```

Above error is displayed when I am using `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2` selenium version on firefox browser:

Below is sample code:

```
act.clickAndHold(dragElement).moveToElement(dropElement).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't use beta version, there may be many bugs.

You need to downgrade your `selenium` version and [download last stable version of selenium 2](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/) and work with `Actions` class until final version of `selenium 3` would not be released.